# $|X| \equiv |\mathrm{Fix}_G(X)| \pmod p$ if $G$ is an infinite $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

> If $G$ is $p$-group acting on a finite set $X$, prove that $|X| \equiv |\mathrm{Fix}_G(X)|\pmod p$.

I've proved it when $G$ is a finite group using the equation $|X| = |\mathrm{Fix}_G(X)| + \sum |O(x_i)|$ and the fact that $|G| = p^k$. In that situation as $|O(x_i)|$ $|$ $|G|$ then $|O(x_i)|$ is a multiple of p so that taking congruences on both sides I get the result.

Is this true when $G$ is infinite? Please give me a hint of what I should use or a counterexample.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $G$ is infinite, the action on $X$ has to factor through a finite quotient of $G$ since $X$ is finite.

Comment: i don't understand very well "the action on X has to factor through a finite quotient of G"...maybe with symbols is clearer what you mean...

Comment: An action of a group on a finite set is the same thing as a homomorphism to the symmetric group on that set.  The image of this homomorphism in your situation is then a finite $p$-group, and the orbits, fixed points, etc for the action of the big group are the same as the orbits of the action of this finite group.